# strict convexity of $\boldsymbol{\beta} \mapsto \| \mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2$

Tags: regression, lasso, convex

So I'm studying lasso regression using https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf and on page 84 (the beginning of section 6.1) it is stated that $\boldsymbol{\beta} \mapsto \| \mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2$ (where $\mathbf{Y}$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, $\mathbf{X}$ is a $n\times p$ matrix and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a $p\times 1$ vector ) is not strictly convex when we are the high dimensionality setting. That is when $p>n$. I'm not sure how this follows and could use some help.

Comment: I believe you have all of the information you need to write your own answer to this question in the Answer box below. Doing so would benefit you because you can gain points from both the question and the answer.

Comment: @statman ...and it will also remove this post from the "unanswered questions" queue. So please post the answer as an answer, not as an update to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This analysis is intended to illuminate the basic underlying ideas.**

Consider the system of linear equations

$$X\gamma = 0$$

where $\gamma$ is a column $p$ vector and $0$ is the zero $n$ vector.  **When $p\gt n$ there are more equations $n$ than unknowns $p,$ whence there must be a *nonzero* solution $\gamma.$**

Assuming there is a $\beta$ that minimizes the form $Q(\beta)= ||Y - X\beta||^2,$ this result about solving linear equations implies there are many minimizers of $Q$ because for any number $t,$

$$Y - X(\beta+t\gamma) = Y - (X\beta + X(t\gamma)) =Y-X\beta-t(X\gamma)= Y-X\beta - 0 = Y-X\beta$$

shows that $Q(\beta+t\gamma)=Q(\beta)$ also minimizes $Q.$  But that's not possible for a *strictly* convex form $Q$, because strict convexity would imply that

$$\begin{aligned}
\color{red}{Q(\beta)} &= Q(\beta+t\gamma)= Q((1-t)\beta+t(\beta+\gamma)) \\
&\color{red}\lt (1-t)Q(\beta) + tQ(\beta+\gamma) = (1-t)Q(\beta) + tQ(\beta) \\&= \color{red}{Q(\beta)},
\end{aligned}$$

a contradiction.

---

I leave it to you to prove (or believe) that any quadratic form $Q$ always has at least one minimizer.  That's the only fact we needed about $Q$ *qua* function of $Y-X\beta.$  Thus, this general result about non-strict convexity holds for *any* function of $Y-X\beta$ having at least one minimizer.  (This includes functions that are not differentiable or even continuous, cases where resorting to Calculus will not work.  In particular, the loss functions used in the Lasso and the Elastic Net are not everywhere differentiable, so this generality can be useful.)

Comment: This probably stems from me not fully understanding quadratic forms, but doesn't quadratic forms have the form $Q=x^TAx$? I can't really see how $\| Y-X\beta\|_2^2$ is on that form.

Comment: $$||Y - X\beta||^2 = (Y-X\beta)^\prime (Y-X\beta) = \beta^\prime (X^\prime X)\beta - (Y^\prime X + X^\prime Y)\beta + Y^\prime Y$$ exhibits $Q$ in the form $\beta\to \beta^\prime A\beta +2 B\beta + C,$ which is a general quadratic form.  It can be written as a quadratic form by padding $A$ with the vectors $B$ and $B^\prime$ on the bottom and right, placing $C$ at the bottom right, and extending $\beta$ with the constant coefficient $1.$ But one of my main points is that none of these details matter.

Comment: Ahh I see. That's a really nice generalization. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First note that $$\frac{\partial^2 \| \mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}^T}=2\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}.$$A function is strictly convex if the hessian is positive definite and convex if it is positive semidefinite. $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is always positive semidefinite so $\boldsymbol{\beta} \mapsto \| \mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2$ is convex. However when $p>n$ $\mathbf{X}$ will not have full rank and since $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is positive definite if and only if $\mathbf{X}$ has full rank we get that $\boldsymbol{\beta} \mapsto \| \mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2$ is only strictly convex when $n>p$ and thus convex when $p>n$.